# Use checkbox in listview and get the value of them android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I am developing an app that get pictures from a server by j-son and show them to user in a list-view that they can choose some pic for download by check-box.

I want to use 2 array-list:

- one for the pic urls
- another one for check-box value

My problem is I don't know much about list-views. check-box of special row must change when user click on that row, and how to get the check-box value from list-view (more important).

```
 void pics(JSONArray data){
   String url;int i;
   for (i=0;i<data.length();i++){
       try {
           String u=data.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("res2").getString("url");
           String t=data.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("images").getJSONObject("resolution1").getString("url");
           myList.add(t);
           Lists.add(u);
           url=data.getJSONObject(i).getString("type");
         if (url.equals("video"))
             continue;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
   try {
    if(i<data.length()){
       String t=data.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("videos").getJSONObject("standard_resolution").getString("url");
       myList.set(i, t);}
    else{


    }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the model what @SKT suggested.
You can create the list of type Image data as-

```
List<ImageData> imagedatas= new ArrayList<>();
```

Now you can add the instances of image data in the for loop as-

```
ImageData imageData = new ImageData();
imageData.setUrl(u);
```

Now you need to create your custom adapter if you have not already created and need set a checked `OnCheckedChangeListener`on the `CheckBox` and need to modify the value of the `ImageData` model accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a ModelClass ImageData

```
class ImageData {
   private String url;
   private boolean isChecked;

   public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
       this.ischecked         = checked;
   }

   public void setUrl(String url) {
       this.url               = url;
   }

   public boolean isChecked() {
       return ischecked;
   }

   public String getUrl() {
       return url;
   }
}
```

Save the json in this model class and add to arraylist. Pass this in your adapter and bind view accordingly. When user clicks a list item change the isChecked value of corresponding model class. Click events can be handled inside the baseadapter class's `getView` method

or

if listitemclick is implemented set

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in XML